# How to request user input (In-Line)

Tags: c#, console-application

So getting and checking user input is easy and all, but when working with the C# Console Application how does one request input inline?

**EG:**

```
What is your name : (USER WRITES HERE)
```

Also, since I am on the topic of Console Applications, how do you detect when the user presses any key? The readline function only responds to enter, but say I want to pause until they press any key, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Console.ReadKey()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Aeeii, I did google beforehand by the way. I searched multiple variants of "In Line Input Request" etc. and nothing popped up for me. As for the Key thing that was just on my mind and I thought now would be a good of a time as ever to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use `Console.Write()` in that case instead of `Console.WriteLine()` like

```
Console.Write("What is your name :");
```

> how do you detect when the user presses any key?

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is accurate on both questions. The question itself is basic, but don't fault @Rahul for answering it.

Comment: while the question gets a rolleyes for not googling, this is a precise and accurate answer

Comment: @BugFinder - didnt even have to use google he seems to know the method `WrtieLine` and `ReadLine` even IntelliSense could have given him the correct answer -> type `Console.Read` read and `oh look what we have here a ReadKey that sounds great`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue. I guess I misunderstood the use of ```Console.Write()``` I thought it was for single character inputs rather than the whole line. Also for the ```Console.ReadKey()```, thank you very much for this information.

Comment: Yeah ive always wondered why people ignore other methods/properties of things.. but..